# Slow APNS on IBM Bluemix

Tags: apple-push-notifications, ibm-cloud

I developed a PHP backend for a mobile app that runs as an Bluemix CF app. I use custom PHP code to send push notifications via APNS. Everything works but the connection to APNS is extremly slow. The same app uses GCM for push Android devices and this works great. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

It is not uncommon to see a delay in APNs Push Notifications as seen in some of the other posts:

[Apple's APNS Delivery is Sometimes Slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291558/apples-apns-delivery-is-sometimes-slow)

[How much delay of ios push notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204767/how-much-delay-of-ios-push-notification)

In regards to PHP specifically I also found a post about delay in connection:

[Pushing notifications using ApnsPHP is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29992750/pushing-notifications-using-apnsphp-is-slow)

Finally I will share with you a document from Apple showing the architecture of APNs in order to get a better idea of how and where the delay may occur:

[Apple Push Service](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)